# How to view the permissions/roles associated with a specific service account in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I tried with the `kubectl get sa default` command, but only see some very basic values. What's the command to view the permissions/roles associated with a specific service account in k8s?

Answer (score 34):

The following command could help. It basically gets the RoleBindings and ClusterRoleBindings which .subjects[0] is the name of the ServiceAccount.

```
$ kubectl get rolebinding,clusterrolebinding --all-namespaces -o jsonpath='{range .items[?(@.subjects[0].name=="SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME")]}[{.roleRef.kind},{.roleRef.name}]{end}'
```

Note: it will not list the RoleBindings / ClusterRoleBindings which contain several objects in the subject field

For instance, if weave-net is deployed as the network plugin, you can get the  Role and ClusterRole used by the weave-net ServiceAccount:

```
$ kubectl get rolebinding,clusterrolebinding --all-namespaces -o jsonpath='{range .items[?(@.subjects[0].name=="weave-net")]}[{.roleRef.kind},{.roleRef.name}]{end}'
[Role,weave-net][ClusterRole,weave-net]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is really great! Thanks for this.

Answer (score 33):

```
kubectl get rolebindings,clusterrolebindings \
--all-namespaces  \
-o custom-columns='KIND:kind,NAMESPACE:metadata.namespace,NAME:metadata.name,SERVICE_ACCOUNTS:subjects[?(@.kind=="ServiceAccount")].name'
```

you can try this command to generate a table to show the mapping

[image]

Comment: Or just use 

`kubectl get rolebindings,clusterrolebindings --all-namespaces -o wide`

Then grep for the name of your service account

Answer (score 11):

The issue with all the answers above is that they rely on you doing additional legwork to then compile all of the `RoleBindings` and/or `ClusterRoleBindings` and any duplicate policies that are granted by them into one master list you can reference for a given user/group/serviceaccount.

After a good deal of searching, I found [`rbac-tool`](https://github.com/alcideio/rbac-tool).

#### Lookup Bindings

Use the [`lookup` command](https://github.com/alcideio/rbac-tool#rbac-tool-lookup) to see all `Roles` or `ClusterRoles` that are bound to a user or service account.

For example, this will print the `Roles` and `ClusterRoles` for the `default` `ServiceAccount`.

```bash
rbac-tool lookup default

  SUBJECT                         | SUBJECT TYPE   | SCOPE       | NAMESPACE             | ROLE
+---------------------------------+----------------+-------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
  default                         | ServiceAccount | ClusterRole |                       | cluster-admin
  default                         | ServiceAccount | Role        | openshift-marketplace | 29517457e658582846e43460363c3ffde708b018f636a66cc7e33076254bff4
  default                         | ServiceAccount | ClusterRole | rook-ceph             | psp:rook
  system:serviceaccounts:default  | Group          | ClusterRole | default               | system:image-puller
```

#### Display RBAC Policies

Use the [`policy-rules` command](https://github.com/alcideio/rbac-tool#rbac-tool-policy-rules) to see all resources and RBAC rules granted to a specific user or service account.

```bash
rbac-tool policy-rules system:serviceaccounts:default

  TYPE  | SUBJECT                        | VERBS | NAMESPACE | API GROUP          | KIND                | NAMES | NONRESOURCEURI | ORIGINATED FROM
+-------+--------------------------------+-------+-----------+--------------------+---------------------+-------+----------------+-----------------------------------+
  Group | system:serviceaccounts:default | get   | default   | core               | imagestreams/layers |       |                | ClusterRoles>>system:image-puller
  Group | system:serviceaccounts:default | get   | default   | image.openshift.io | imagestreams/layers |       |                | ClusterRoles>>system:image-puller
```

Answer (score 8):

I think you are looking for command: `kubectl auth can-i --list` and `kubectl auth can-i --list --as=[user-name]`

Sample output:

```
kubectl auth can-i --list 
Resources                                       Non-Resource URLs                     Resource Names              Verbs
selfsubjectaccessreviews.authorization.k8s.io   []                                    []                          [create]
selfsubjectrulesreviews.authorization.k8s.io    []                                    []                          [create]
persistentvolumeclaims                          []                                    []                          [get list watch create delete deletecollection patch update]
pods/exec                                       []                                    []                          [get list watch create delete deletecollection patch update]
pods                                            []                                    []                          [get list watch create delete deletecollection patch update]
events                                          []                                    []                          [get list watch]
pods/log                                        []                                    []                          [get list watch]
configmaps                                      []                                    []                          [get watch list]
                                                [/.well-known/openid-configuration]   []                          [get]
                                                [/api/*]                              []                          [get]
                                                [/api]                                []                          [get]
                                                [/apis/*]                             []                          [get]
                                                [/apis]                               []                          [get]
                                                [/healthz]                            []                          [get]
                                                [/healthz]                            []                          [get]
                                                [/livez]                              []                          [get]
                                                [/livez]                              []                          [get]
                                                [/openapi/*]                          []                          [get]
                                                [/openapi]                            []                          [get]
                                                [/openid/v1/jwks]                     []                          [get]
                                                [/readyz]                             []                          [get]
                                                [/readyz]                             []                          [get]
                                                [/version/]                           []                          [get]
                                                [/version/]                           []                          [get]
                                                [/version]                            []                          [get]
                                                [/version]                            []                          [get]
podsecuritypolicies.policy                      []                                    [global-unrestricted-psp]   [use]
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the `Role` name which bound to the serviceaccount `default` using the following command.
`kubectl get  rolebinding --output=yaml` or `kubectl get  clusterrolebinding --output=yaml`

Now get the role config using
`kubectl get role rolenamefrompreviouscommands`

Answer (score 0):

In Kubernetes, service account is mapped to privileges (cluster level or namespace level) using ClusterRoleBinding object. You need to lookup the RoleBinding or ClusterRoleBinding object and then look up the Role or ClusterRole object to see what privileges it has in the cluster.