# how to retrieve current user granted RBAC with kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, rbac

One can create `Role` or `ClusterRole` and assign it to user via `RoleBinding` or `ClusterRoleBinding`.

from user view that have a token, how to get all granted permissions or roles\rolebindings applied to him via `kubectl`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
  # Check to see if I can do everything in my current namespace ("*" means all)
  kubectl auth can-i '*' '*'

  # Check to see if I can create pods in any namespace
  kubectl auth can-i create pods --all-namespaces

  # Check to see if I can list deployments in my current namespace
  kubectl auth can-i list deployments.extensions
```

you can get further information with `kubectl auth --help` command

You can also  impersonate as a different user to check their permission with the following flag `--as` or `--as-group`

```
kubectl auth can-i create deployments --namespace default --as john.cena
```

Comment: Can I figure ou somehowt where all these permissions come from?

Comment: all of these permission are part of the role/clusterrole. you can get the role and see the rules inside, for example, `kubectl get role $ADMIN -o yaml`

Answer (score 19):

I think you are looking for command `kubectl auth can-i --list` for listing all user permissions:

```
Resources                                       Non-Resource URLs                     Resource Names              Verbs
selfsubjectaccessreviews.authorization.k8s.io   []                                    []                          [create]
selfsubjectrulesreviews.authorization.k8s.io    []                                    []                          [create]
persistentvolumeclaims                          []                                    []                          [get list watch create delete deletecollection patch update]
pods/exec                                       []                                    []                          [get list watch create delete deletecollection patch update]
pods                                            []                                    []                          [get list watch create delete deletecollection patch update]
events                                          []                                    []                          [get list watch]
pods/log                                        []                                    []                          [get list watch]
configmaps                                      []                                    []                          [get watch list]
                                                [/.well-known/openid-configuration]   []                          [get]
                                                [/api/*]                              []                          [get]
                                                [/api]                                []                          [get]
                                                [/apis/*]                             []                          [get]
                                                [/apis]                               []                          [get]
                                                [/healthz]                            []                          [get]
                                                [/healthz]                            []                          [get]
                                                [/livez]                              []                          [get]
                                                [/livez]                              []                          [get]
                                                [/openapi/*]                          []                          [get]
                                                [/openapi]                            []                          [get]
                                                [/openid/v1/jwks]                     []                          [get]
                                                [/readyz]                             []                          [get]
                                                [/readyz]                             []                          [get]
                                                [/version/]                           []                          [get]
                                                [/version/]                           []                          [get]
                                                [/version]                            []                          [get]
                                                [/version]                            []                          [get]
podsecuritypolicies.policy                      []                                    [global-unrestricted-psp]   [use]
```

You can also see another user permissions by adding `--as=[user-name]`

For example: `kubectl auth can-i --list --as=jenkins`

As for more granular information of roles, cluster roles per service account or specific actions (verbs) allowed to performed on specific resources refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71387351/1264304) answer.