# How to check if I have enough permission to start a cron job

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have two applications running in K8s, 1 application run as deployment, the other application run as cronjob. Suppose that this application will trigger the cronjob run in some situation. However, it works before but now it fails. I suspect may because the K8s admin has some permission / role restriction apply.

```
try {
    v2alpha1CronJob = batchV2alpha1Api.readNamespacedCronJob('A-CRONJOB-NAME', 'A-NAMESPACE', null, null, null);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Here I get error, it promot me error as following
}
```

Error is:

```
Error trying to manipulate k8s CronJob {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"the server could not find the requested resource","reason":"NotFound","details":{},"code":404}
```

Would I know what I should do now? My k8s server version is 1.21.5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to view the permissions/roles associated with a specific service account in k8s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54602224/how-to-view-the-permissions-roles-associated-with-a-specific-service-account-in)

Comment: @Micheal In your request I see `batchV2alpha1Api`, but in the error: `"apiVersion":"v1"` Based on this, which apiVersion has CronJob in definition and what API group for [CronJob is enabled now](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/#enabling-or-disabling)? `kubectl api-resources`

Comment: hi @AndrewSkorkin , please write down formal answer here, and I will take it as your answer is correct :)

Comment: Hello @Micheal Could you please check the provided answer?

Answer (score 0):

The error that shows specifies that it is not finding the resource, 404 error. If it were a problem with the permissions you would have the 403 error.

```
"message":"the server could not find the requested resource"
```

You should check if the requested resource is the correct one or if it really exists.

Answer (score 0):

The description for the CronJob in the question contains `batchV2alpha1Api`. This means that the version of the API group is **batch/v2alpha1**.

But in the error description there is another version of the API group `"apiVersion":"v1"` - **batch/v1**.

Due to this difference, the CronJob cannot be created, as there is no required version of the Kubernetes API to create this object.

**To fix this problem you can:**

1. Change the apiVersion in the description for CronJob with the version currently used by Kubernetes

or

2. [Enable required API group](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/#enabling-or-disabling) and don't change the description.